# Accessibility and site design -- acceptance tick and colour blindness

Tags: bug, design

A user, @ran2, commented on [this question/answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/7876/interpreting-range-bars-in-rs-plot-stl/7880#7880) that they found it difficult to determine that they had accepted an answer because of their colour blindness and the choice of colour for the accepted-tick.

Could the site designers adopt a different colour for such critical parts of the site and thus make the site more accessible?

Thanks for considering this.

Answer (score 6):

When converted to greyscale, the intensity of the green check is fairly similar to the vote grey. So perhaps they're right:

[image]

Comment: the user is also on SO and they found the tick there easier to handle. Perhaps the background on CV plus the shade used is more important than simply the colour, as SO also uses green.

Comment: Actually, I think the key advantage of SO's checks is that they're hollow until checked.  CV's checks are solid in both states.

Comment: @Gavin There exist different [color defects](http://www.InternetTG.org/newsletter/mar99/accessibility_color_challenged.html), although with different prevalence in the population, so I think we should not focus on the color *per se* as you suggest. I think that adopting SO design would be a good idea.

Comment: @Matt Parker - you hit the nail on the head there I think Matt. Having a clear difference to the not accepted and accepted states is a good suggestion.

Comment: @chl - good point. I was remiss in suggesting using a new colour in my Q. I mean't some other means of indicating accepted rather than relying on shade or colour.

Comment: @Gavin Yes, I understood it this way, sorry my response was unclear.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the [MinimalOverflow](https://stackapps.com/questions/2143/minimaloverflow-a-themescript-for-stackexchange) is some way to go; AFAIK it is considered to be implemented as SE-wide lightweight and accessible theme variant (there is a mobile common version already).